# Gmail label scaling limitations?

Tags: gmail, trello-organization, gmail-labels

Are there any issues with creating a lot of labels in Gmail?

Things such as:

- Limit to the number of labels that can be created?
- UI concerns?
- Performance issues?
- Conflicts with certain Labs features or 3rd party software?

I can think of two:

- The label list on the left will be very large making it hard to find the labels you want. One solution is to use the Gmail Nested Labels Lab, which helps organize them.
- The iPhone mail client will present labels as a flat list, so it may be hard to get to the ones at the bottom.

I'd like to know which limitations I may run into before I decide to use this method.

Answer (score 4):

I have about **70 labels** in my Gmail. I am not aware of the limit ot the number of labels you can have...
I use **nested labels** and **label colouring** - no problems. I have not noticed any other performance issues or conflicts with other features/software.

**UI concerns**... Yes, the list on the left is very long. However, I hardly even find that a problem. The **visibility controls** of labels are very helpful. The most frequently used/important labels are set to *show*, other used to *show if unread*, the rest - to *hide*. Then I use the search bar with `label:[xyz]` to navigate to more obscure labels.

Overall, I love the ability to create as many label as I like. Makes the management and use of Gmail so much easier.

Comment: For my **most** important labels, I put punctuation (`!`, `-`, etc.) at the front of the label, forcing them to the top of the list.

Comment: @Al Everett, great point!